# Do I need to re-index my site in Google Search Console when migrating from Wix to WordPress with new hosting?

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, migration

My client was running on Wix, so I moved his website over to WordPress with Godaddy. Same domain name.

Do I need to delete and re add the website properties in Google search console? I resubmitted the sitemap and fetched all pages with the new site (I also rebuilt the site), but the preview image for the property is still showing the Wix site.

It's been about 4 days. Does this just take time or do I need to re-add the site? If I do, will google still have my sitemap/robots/etc information or does this need to be re-done?

Is there any downside to just re submitting the site?

Comment: The Yoast SEO section for google search console is also showing no indexed url's even though they are indexed on the google search console interface.

Comment: You do not have to do anything as far as Google is concerned. Search engines are not real-time. It will take time to reflect your new site in the search results. It will all work as intended, but it may take days and weeks to see results. No need to delete/add properties, sitemaps, and the like. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you moved to Wix to WordPress, your URLs likely changed.   You need to implement 301 permanent redirects between every Wix URL to every WordPress URL.

Here is [an article about Wix to WordPress migration](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-convert-wix-to-wordpress-a-complete-guide-to-all-your-options) that suggests the [CMS2CMS Wix to WordPress plugin for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cms2cms-wix-to-wp-migrator/).  It appears that that plugin can set up the redirects for you.

Deleting and re-adding the site in Search Console will have no effect.   Without implementing the redirects, Google will not quickly process the new website structure.   Any rankings in Google search will go away.

Comment: I recreated the new website using exactly the same url's, with the expectation that when google is given new sitemaps and decides to crawl the site it would update....is this not correct? I did then change a few of them...I want the ones from the wix site to simply disappear because the site literally had no SEO value (it was on page 4). I have disconnected the wix site from any domain. Do I still need to 301 redirect those pages until google drops them?

Comment: If those pages are gone, it is best to give them a "410 Gone" status.  Google will drop them the next time they are crawled.  That would typically be within two weeks unless you have more than a couple hundred pages.  Even a "404 Not Found" page will be removed after the next crawl once Google gives it a 24 hour grace period to re-appear.

Comment: Actually I need more help....there is no feature to 301 redirect from a wix site to a wordpress site. I also cannot find anyway of setting a 410. The stupid platform doesn't even have a real 404 page feature...is there another way to do it from outside of wix?

Comment: I thought your site was now on WordPress?   I need to implement any redirects or 410s under your new site.   There are WordPress plugins that allow those, or you can add your *.htacess* file.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify. I did not "transfer" the site. I simply built a new one on wordpress and transferred the domain over to the new host and disconnected it from the old wix site. I'm asking if I need to 301 or 410 the existing wix pages, or will google figure this out on their own in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Google can no longer access the wix site.  As I said, you need to redirect any URLs that changed.  That redirect must be implemented on your new site.

Comment: But if I choose not to, they will simply be dropped right?

Comment: Those pages now give a 404 error.  Google will drop those pages from the index the next time it tries to crawl them.  That would probably happen within two weeks.

Answer (score 1):

If URLs are the same which suppose to be same when you are changing (only) hosting. Then no need for reindexing.